# SolrEntityProcessor is called only once for sub-entities

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm using Solr 4.2, and I am trying to call [SolrEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) as a **sub-entity**. So far, only one call is made to Solr and a single document is indexed while all others are ignored. This *should* be possible, but it doesn't seem to work... Any ideas?

Code snippist:

```
<document>
  <entity dataSource="psql" name="user" query="SELECT * FROM users";>
    <field column="id" name="user_id" />

    <entity name="liked_items" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://localhost:8983/solr/items" query="user_liking_this:${user.id}" rows="1000" fl="item_id" >
      <field column="item_id" name="item_id" />
    </entity>

  </entity>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found my answer in [this Solr JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3336). Tested and working as expected!

The solution is to use the patched `SolrEntityProcessor` [attached to the issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12526721/SolrEntityProcessor.java) instead of the one included in the DataImportHandler JAR.

Note that **you will need it for any Solr version up to and including 4.3.0 (and possibly higher)** - despite what the issue status and comments say, the patch does not appear to be included in any existing  version.