# How to patch Solr4.2 for SolrEnityProcessor Sub-Enity issue

Tags: solr, solr4

According to [SolrEntityProcessor is called only once for sub-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734308/solrentityprocessor-is-called-only-once-for-sub-entities/) we can use the patched SolrEntityProcessor in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3336?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel to solve the subentity problem.

I tried renaming the jar file to zip and then try replacing the patched file but as I got only java file I can't replace it with class file. So I drop this idea.

Here is then what I have tried. I decompiled the original jar solr-dataimporthandler-4.2.0.jar present in solr 4.2 package. Then I replace the patch file. And try to compile the files for making the jar again. But I started getting compilation errors.

.\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: ')' expected

/* 432 / if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: expected / 432 / if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: not a statem ent / 432 / if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: illegal star t of expression / 432 */ if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: ';' expected

/* 432 */ if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:397: ';' expected

/* 432 / if (XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.get()) { ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:398: not a statem ent / 433 */ XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$throwExp.set(false); ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:398: ';' expected

/* 433 / XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$throwExp.set(false); ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:406: not a statem ent / 442 */ XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.set(true); ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:406: ';' expected

/* 442 / XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.val$isEnd.set(true); ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:409: not a statem ent / 445 */ XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.offer(row); ^ .\org\apache\solr\handler\dataimport\XPathEntityProcessor.java:409: ';' expected

/* 445 */ XPathEntityProcessor.2.this.offer(row); ^ 12 errors

Any idea how to patch Solr4.2 for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3336) that you are referring to has been fixed and closed in Solr 3.6.1 more than a year ago (May 2012).

This means that the fix should already be available in 4.2. You do not need to apply this patch anymore.

Edit -1

I compared the `SolrEntityProcessor.java` file attached in the [SOLR-3336](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3336) with the [3.6](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/SolrEntityProcessor.java) and [trunk](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/SolrEntityProcessor.java) branch. I couldn't see any difference besides come cleanup of print statements. This is because the patch has been committed to 3.6 onwards.

If you think there is still an issue, it may not be the one addressed in this issue, which could mean that patching with this file isn't going to help you. You are welcome to carry on this exercise, but I would recommend making sure that you are on track (by collaborating with the Solr Devs). I have a feeling that you may be looking at a different issue, if any.

Comment: But the fix is not in this till 4.2 or even 4.4. It is also discussed that the fix is not included in branch in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734308/solrentityprocessor-is-called-only-once-for-sub-entities/15740320#15740320

Comment: This should be verified in the mailing list - I would recommend dropping an email or IRC. Contact details [are here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/discussion.html)

Comment: I mailed them also. But please any help will be really great.

Comment: The issue of Solr mentioned above is now reopened in JIRA.

Comment: @user766061 - neat, hope someone with context can help you out on this.